# What is different between Basic and Basic + Test Plans

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

where I can see compare test plans? In general,  "Basic + Test Plans" is include: Create and manage Test Plans. Do you have any additional information?

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find description: [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops)

Basic + Test Plans:

> **Test Case Management**
>
> Includes adding [test plans and test suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops),
> [creating manual test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-test-cases?view=azure-devops), [deleting test artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/delete-test-artifacts?view=azure-devops) and
> [testing different configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/test-different-configurations?view=azure-devops)
>
> **Test Execution and Test Analysis**
>
> Includes [running manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-manual-tests?view=azure-devops), [tracking test status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/track-test-status?view=azure-devops) and [automated tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Basic:

> **Test Execution and Test Analysis**
>
> Includes [running manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-manual-tests?view=azure-devops), [tracking test status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/track-test-status?view=azure-devops) and [automated tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1):

Important: Be aware also that the "Basic + Test Plans" costs like x10 the price of the "Basic" licence, monthly.  So choose who has it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic + Test Plans**: Provides access to all features included in Basic, as well as Azure Test Plans.

This [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops#license-requirements) describes the license requirements in more detail:

[image]